# Crash app for search bar with - rangeOfString:options:

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I've implemented a search bar in my app.

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar   
 {
    [_tableView_Rego resignFirstResponder];
 }

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString 
 *)searchText
 {
    if(searchText.length == 0)
 {
    isFiltered = NO;
 }
 else
 {
      isFiltered = YES;
      arrayFilter = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      for (NSString *str in arrayNameList)
     {
        NSRange stringRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText 
         options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (stringRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [arrayFilter addObject:str];
        }
    }
  }
   [_tableView_Rego reloadData];
  }
```

It works when I provided a static data in `arrayNameList`, but when I provide dynamic data through the backend, it crashes with this error:

> -[nameListMClass rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x60000042dda0

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your array `arrayNameList` contains an object of class `nameListMClass` which is probably not a string and doesn't provide a method `rangeOfString:options:`. You should inspect the members of `arrayNameList` and check where they come from.